# how to handle requirejs conflicts

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a javascript plugin which can be added in any website. I am using requirejs in my plugin. When it is added to a website, which already has requirejs, I am getting script errors and the plugin is not working. I cannot find any noconflict method for requirejs. Suggest a solution.

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () { return io; }
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
```

Similar case: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712463/create-a-requirejs-module-that-can-be-added-into-any-page-without-conflict?rq=1)

Comment: I think you need to add a bit more information for anyone to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, use old style Javascript methods to determine if requireJS is already part of the environment; if so, make no mention of adding requireJS; if not, then add it to the environment in the usual fashion (perhaps using document.write to emit a html script tag to invoke requirejs